# What is the relationship between discrete data and infiniteness?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I took discrete mathematics last semester and I still do not understand how discrete data/sets relate to infiniteness. For example, in the preface of *Schaum's Outline of Discrete Math*, it states that, "Discrete mathematics, the study of finite systems, has become increasingly important as the computer age has advanced." However, some people have said that discrete math is not only limited to finite systems, but also infinite systems.

In the world of mathematics, are discrete objects/sets ONLY finite, or can they also be infinite?

Thanks in advance for answering, and have a great rest of your day!

Comment: Sometimes infinite systems are reasonable models for finite systems or can make arguments about an infinite class of finite systems in a meaningful way. I think using generating functions for counting problems is a good example of this since infinite series can be used to tackle finite problems.